# Java: How to return object of not known child class from another class (not parent)?

Tags: java, class, parent-child

I googled a lot, but it seems I don't know a term which describe this situation, because I am pretty new in programming. 
I have an absctract class. Something like this:

```
public abstract A { 
...
public void randomize() {...} 
... 
}
```

And I have a lot of child classes, like `class B extends A, class C extends A`. 
Then I have separate class, which should know the type of a child class. Something like this:

```
public class D {

private Class<? extends A> childClassType; 

public C(Class<? extends A> type) { ... }
....
}
```

The thing is: this class should have a method which should return object of child class (that is passed as a parameter here). So that I could cast some value to his type and call randomize() method.

So basically, I need something like this inside C class:

```
public [???] neededMethod() {
libraryMethodRequiringClassAsParameter(childClassType);
....
[???] childObject = ([???]) libraryMethodReturningObject();
childObject.randomize();
return childObject;
}
```

I don't know syntax of [???], because I don't know how such situation is called. I can just create A object (it works), but then I will need double-cast (inside from object to A, outside from A to it's child), which seems stupid.

Will be appreciate for any info.

Comment: Why can't you just pass the child object as parameter? All children of ``A`` will have the method ``randomize()`` available.

Comment: Ideally, it shouldn't exist before this class is called. And even if I create it somewhere else, how to define that neededMethod should get as a parameter object of child class (which exactly, not known) of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the following code to work. Hopefully it matches your requirements:

```
public class A {
    ... 
    public static void doStuff(Class<? extends B> clazz) {
        try {
            C obj = clazz.newInstance();
            obj.randomize();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        }       
    }

}

abstract class B {
    abstract void randomize();
}

class C extends B {
    ...
    public void randomize() {
        System.out.println("works");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but the term you might be looking for is `generic class`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) is some documentation on it, applied to your code you could have something like this

```
public class D<T> {
    ...
    public T neededMethod() {...}
}
```

Comment: I looked through it documetation, but the thing is: T should not be arbitrary, it should be child of A.

Comment: And moreover, I need to know inside the method which exactly. I cannot pass T or T.class to the libraryMethodRequiringClassAsParameter().

Answer (score 0):

Your class D that contains the type should be generic for the type it's being used with.

```
public class D<T extends A> {

    private Class<T> childClassType; 

    public D(Class<T> type) { ... }
        ....
    }

    public T neededMethod() {
           T childObject = (T)libraryMethodRequiringClassAsParameter(childClassType);
           childObject.randomize();
           return childObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Object` as a data type? In Java, `Object` is the super class of all classes.

```
public Object neededMethod() {
    libraryMethodRequiringClassAsParameter(childClassType);
    ....
    Object childObject = libraryMethodReturningObject();
    if(childObject instanceof ClassFoo) {
        ((ClassFoo)childObject).randomize();
    }
    return childObject;
}
```